# vba countif on multiple sheets

Tags: vba, match, lookup, countif

please find the below code and comments in between

```
Sub Test()

Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim myempid As Variant

For Each wSheet In Worksheets

    Select Case (wSheet.Name)

        Case "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"

        empid2 = Worksheets("DB").Range("C13").Value2

        With Worksheets(wSheet.Name)

           'locate the row for the value
            myempid = Application.Match(empid2, .Columns("D"), 0)

            If IsError(myvalueRow) Then
                Debug.Print "empid not found in column D"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If myempid >= 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Hi")

            '***
```

> '(instead of the message box , i need to count the value "PL" from
>   ("F5:AJ500") for example if myempid is in a _
>               col range("D8") of sheet jan , we need to count from (F8:AJ8). like wise all the values of myempid should be count in each
>   and every sheets._
>               'the sum total of count (PL) in all sheets matching the myempid should be displayed in a msgbox.

---

```
            End If
      End With

      Case Else

    End Select

Next wSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish.  What kind of data are you working with?  How will `C13' trigger a macro?  Have you tried searching for examples of `COUNTIF`?  What have you tried?  Also, check out the [tour], as well as [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: C13 triggers a macro as i have added a code in cell change for the sheet.

i have searched for count if but i'm not sure how to calculate all the counts in the sheets from (jan to dec).

In jan to dec row D contains a unique id , that id is entered in the specific cell of sheet DB (c13).

hope this is clear

Comment: ^^column D? If you enter an ID in cell C13 of sheet DB do you then want a count of this ID in each column D of everysheet? The count anywhere in the 12 sheets? Where is this number returned to? Showing us a worked example with expected result might help.

Comment: I have edited the code and comments are added in between, please have look .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***`Range`* `.` `Column`** to return the column number of a cell from a range object. Also you can use **`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf`** to count cells in a range that contain a certain value.

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but based on your example, if you have a specific cell reference (for example, in an object like `MyCell` below), you could adapt this:

```
Sub myCountIf()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myCell = Range("D8")
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("DB").Range("F" & myCell.Column & ":AJ" & myCell.Column), "PL")
End Sub
```

Here's more info on the [`WorksheetFunction.CountIf` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countif-method-excel).